# Find the (unique) 9-dimensional ellipsoid of maximum volume lying with the convex set of 4 x 4 symmetric, positive-definite (trace 1) matrices

Tags: matrix, mathematical-optimization, physics, geometry

Find the unique ([JohnEllipsoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_ellipsoid)) maximum volume ellipsoid lying within the 9-dimensional convex set formed by the $4 \times 4$ symmetric, positive-definite ("density") matrices with fixed trace 1.

This is a computationally-oriented follow-up to

[MathoverflowQuestion](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/369287/what-are-the-john-ellipsoids-for-a-pair-of-9-and-15-dimensional-convex-sets-o)

Comment: Extremize the sum of squares of the matrix parameters, subject to the matrix trace and positivity constraints?

Comment: There  is no code or problem formulation here concerning Mathematica.

Comment: I've posted a mathoverflow answer at the indicated site. I, of course, employed Mathematica in the analysis--although perhaps as Alex Trounev commented, it was not a Mathematica question per se.